# Set icon from the current directory in a .desktop file

Tags: .desktop, xdg-open

I have an application in `/home/sourav/project/.src/` directory.

I have a desktop entry to run the application. I have set `Path='./.src'` to the `.desktop` file to run the application from the `src/` and then `Exec=\command`.

I also have an icon in `.src/img/` directory, called `fireworks.svg`. I want to display that image as the icon of the desktop entry.

The problem is that the app can be copied to other computers and stored in any path, so I can't mention `Icon=/home/sourav/projects/.src/img/fireworks.svg`, which doesn't work if the parent directories doesn't exist on other computers.

---

I have tried:

1. `Icon=./.src/img/fireworks.svg`
2. `Icon=/bin/sh -c "echo $PWD/.src/img/fireworks.svg"`

They didn't work at all.

---

Is there a way to show `./src/img/fireworks.svg` as the app icon even after moving or renaming the parent directories?

Comment: Does your application get installed as a package on a users system? If so, then you could drop the icon file in either `/usr/share/icons` or `/usr/share/pixmaps/` and then call the icon by its name directly without providing any path. This is how that is typically done as far as icons go for `.desktop` files.

Comment: Actually the app isn't installed on the system. It is in a folder. It can be moved to any GNU/Linux computer that might not have the icon pack installed...